# BigQuery - Skip Using Reserved Slots (Flat-Rate)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We use [BigQuery Reservations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro) in the form of [monthly commitments](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro#commitments) in order to optimize costs. However, we have seen that some large queries sometimes fail to execute due to `Slot Contention` i.e. unavailability of reserved Slots and inability to switch over to on-demand capacity.

Is there a way we can execute some important queries, within the same project where reservations have been enabled, without reserved slots and purely using on-demand capacity?

Answer (score 1):

the assignments of commitments can be done on organization, folder or project (as the lowest level).

I believe in your case it would be best to have a separate project in the same billing account that you would use to query. This would still allow you to read data from your original project (without needing to transfer it...).

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for `BigQuery Reservations` is to have it in a **separate project within the same billing account** since you will have to create an `admin project` to be able to create **assignments**, **commitments**, and **reservations**.

Considering that you want to use reservations without involving reserved slots, you must refuse to use [Assignments](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro#assignments) for the query to use [On-demand Pricing Model](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing) by default..